# Project design - How to import a Child module in main.py?

Tags: python, python-import

I have the following project design:

```
folder/

    folder/main.py

    folder/package1

        folder/package1/__init__.py (contains __all__ = ["Parent", "Child"])
        folder/package1/Parent.py (abstract class)
        folder/package1/Child.py

    folder/package2
        folder/package2/__init__.py (contains __all__ = ["Class"])
        folder/package2/Class.py
```

In Child.py I have:

```
from Parent import *
```

In main.py, I have:

```
from package1 import Child
```

When I run main.py, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
File ".\folder\main.py", line 2, in <module>
   from package1 import *
File ".\Package1\Child.py", line 1, in <module>
   from Parent import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Parent'
```

When I navigate to package1 then run Child.py via Terminal, it executes without any errors.

Any idea what could be causing the error when running the main.py?

Comment: what environment you used to run first time?

Comment: I have a virtual environment env in: folder/env

Comment: As you are using relative import i suggest using `from .Parent import *` as this will indicate python to search Parent module in current directory

Comment: This solves the error, however I start getting the following when trying to instantiate Child in main.py:

    TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using relative import I suggest using

```
from .Parent import *
```

instead of

```
from Parent import *
```

as this will indicate python to search Parent module in current directory

Comment: This solves the error, however I start getting the following when trying to instantiate Child in main.py: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Thanks @SaGaR. I have actually just figured it out. Beginner's (which I actually am) error in main.py. Since Child.py contains a class of the same name I needed to use the following: from `package1.Child import Child` instead of: `from package1 import Child`

Answer (score 0):

use

```
from folder.package1.Parent import *
```

or

```
from package1.Parent import *
```

depends on your folder system for this project.

but its important to specify the name of package before import module.

Comment: 'folder' is unresolved, however using pakage1.Parent works. Same as in my reply to SaGar, I start getting the error:

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: then provide to us what its the Parent.py module, otherwise i cant help

Comment: Thanks @Alexzander. I have actually just figured it out. Beginner's (which I actually am) error in main.py. Since Child.py contains a class of the same name I needed to use the following:

    `from package1.Child import Child`

instead of:

    `from package1 import Child`